# Is there any consistency regarding time travel in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel

Every so often, there's an episode of *Star Trek* involving time travel, and more often than not, the "rules" seem to change from episode to episode. For example, [Future's End](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Future%27s_End), Braxton explains that they're all caught in a causality loop, which they break out of at the end of the episode. Then, in [Timeless](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Timeless), Kim sends back a transmission and alters the past (he does this multiple times, in fact, and the signals seem to not conflict). In the film [First Contact](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact), it's plausible that the *Phoenix* only flew *because* the *Enterprise* showed up.

It seems like there's not much consistency in the way that time travel works (the closest we get is Annorax's vague explanation in [Year of Hell](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Year_of_Hell_(episode))), but is there a plausible in-universe explanation as to why the "rules" seem to change so much?

Comment: I think the best in-universe explanation for things like this is that we (as the audience) simply don't understand it well enough.  Clearly, in-universe, time doesn't behave like people expected in the 20th and 21st centuries.

Comment: The closest you'll get is probably O'Brien's simultaneous "[I hate temporal mechanics.](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Visionary_(episode))"

Comment: there was a temporal cold war. Mr Spock had hoped to repair the timeline so there is some Vulcan-accessible consistency.

Comment: [Wibbly-wobbly, timey-wimey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vY_Ry8J_jdw)

Comment: I think part of the answer can be found here: [If the Federation has effective time travel, why don't they use it to correct major problems in the past?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71805/2765)

Comment: Trust in the Prophets.

Comment: No. There isn’t.

Answer (score 3):

No Trek show or movie of which I'm aware explains just how timelines and parallel universes work in its own universe. It seems to be a mixture of theories that have presented themselves over the nearly 50 years the show has been around. What we do know includes:

- The "main" timeline can be altered ("Assignment: Earth", "Yesterday's Enterprise," just to name a few)

  - People can cross back from a former version of the "main" timeline ("Yesterday's Enterprise," "Endgame," Abrams' *Star Trek*, etc.). These people remember the altered timeline.
  - People in a "protected" area during timeline modification can remain unaffected by the alteration ("City on the Edge of Forever," *First Contact*).
  - Other non-time-sensitives will not notice any change in the timeline (seen in the above examples). Some, such as Guinan, may be able to sense a change, but be unable to provide details. The effects of these changes on the Q Continuum are undocumented.
- Parallel timelines of generally undefined origin can coexist with the "main" timeline ("Parallels," among other TNG episodes).
- Parallel universes, such as the Mirror Universe, can coexist with all of the above without a defined point of divergence. They seem to operate independently of the "main" timeline except for crossover situations.
- By the TNG era, the Federation has figured out some, most, or all of this, at least to the ability that individuals can recall. By the time of the *Enterprise-J*, perhaps even more is known. Little, if any, information about the discrepancies and theories has been shown on-screen.